# Whose view is not in the window hierarchy after dismissViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, dismiss

I have a view controller that shows the details of an object. On this view controller is an "edit" button which shows modally the edition view controller. When I try to dismiss the modally presented view (edit view controller) :

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

I get the following error and it's presenting my initial viewController instead :

> Warning: Attempt to present ≤Deevent.MyEventsVC: 0x7f99b70160a0≥ on ≤Deevent.EventCreationVC: 0x7f99b7238690≥ whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

So what I've tried was to set the root view controller of my view to the view I wanted to go back and present it in the completition of my dismiss. It's working well, but my application is in a Tabbar Controller and now it's not in it anymore. Same for the navigation controller.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyEventsStoryboard") as! MyEventsVC

let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = vc

self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: {
                    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
```

Is there an other approach for presenting viewControllers after dismiss without leaving the Tabbar controller ?

Thanks

Comment: what are u trying to acheive pls explain a little more

Comment: I have a view controller which shows the details of an object. On this view I have an "edit" button which shows the edition view controller modally. When I try to dismiss the edition view controller, I get the error and instead of showing me my details view controller, it shows me my initial (login) view controller.

Comment: share the code where you are presenting view controller modally

Comment: It's just a performSegueWithIdentifier :
`self.performSegueWithIdentifier("editEvent", sender: self)`

Comment: For the error that you are getting, have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379327/ios-warning-attempt-to-present-viewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-in-the-window

Comment: do you have navigation controller embedded inside your view

Comment: I just went through them and my main problem is not the same. I already tried those solutions, it works but as I said it shows me my vc without the tabbar and navigation controller.

Comment: Did you first embed TabBarController -> Navigation Controller -> View Controller in your storyboard? Could you take a screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: It's a bit complicated. I have my details view which is embed in a navigation controller which is called by a view controller which is itself embed in a navigation controller which is embed in a tabbar controller. Maybe my problem is caused by the two navigation controllers.

Answer (score -2):

Since you are trying to present the new view controller by calling `self.presentViewController` **after** you dismiss `self`, you get the error. I can offer you a solution if you are using a navigation controller.