# Login Window won't open in next view controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, uiviewcontroller, linkedin-api

In my app, I have a Facebook login in my first view controller which redirects to my next view controller after a successful login that has a LinkedIn Login option.

However, after the LinkedIn Login button is pressed, I receive this error.

```
2016-10-17 23:00:42.588 Frieyo[86134:1636422] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "linkedin://" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
2016-10-17 23:00:42.593 Frieyo[86134:1636422] Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7f9fa409ba00> on <Frieyo.TutorialViewController: 0x7f9fa2c04430> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I know it's not a problem with opening the LinkedIn URL because my App Delegate is handling those URL's correctly AND **when I set the LinkedIn view controller as my initial view controller the login WORKS!**

Apparently these answers: [iOS: Warning "attempt to present ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28379327/ios-warning-attempt-to-present-viewcontroller-whose-view-is-not-in-the-window) and [whose view is not in the window hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy) indicate that I should put this method in my viewDidAppear method; however, that is not relevant because I am redirecting to another view after a successful login.

**The problem** (I assume) lies within the view stack. Here's is how I'm am transitioning from the first view controller to the LinkedIn VC.

```
   let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
   let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VerifyLinkedInViewController") as! VerifyLinkedInViewController
   self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

How exactly do I re-write to avoid -***"whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"*** ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126177/discussion-between-rohit-tigga-and-abdul-sathar).

Comment: You have to find storyboard and your view controller then you can move from linkedin view controller

Answer (score 0):

I have just faced this problem, the issue was inside my facebook login method, in the "fromViewController" parameter.

In order to fix it, I had to reference the View Controller that I did the call to the method, instead of instantiate a new one.

EDIT - Code example (that's the one that it's working for me now):

```
func performFacebookSignIn(viewController: UIViewController) {

    let facebookReadPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
    let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

    loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(facebookReadPermissions, fromViewController: viewController, handler: { (result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else if result.isCancelled {
            print("User cancelled login.")
        } else {
            print("Facebook sign in!")
        }
    })
```

Before that, instead of using a "viewController" parameter from the  other ViewController where I called the method, I was instantiating a new View Controller in "fromViewController" parameter (I was doing: MyViewController() as UIViewController) and it was getting me this "window hierarchy" error.

I hope it helps you somehow.

Comment: Samuel, I'm not sure what you mean. Can you explain with code?

Comment: Also I am presenting my nextViewController so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?